# How do I fully qualify type identifiers in generic methods in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, generics, indy10

This question came up when trying to assign the OnUDPRead event on an Indy IdUDPServer component. (DelphiXE Update 1)

The following auto-generated code gives a syntax error "Expected '>' but '.' found":

```
procedure TForm1.IdUDPServer1UDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread;
  AData: TArray<System.Byte>; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
```

I can work around this by changing the declaration to:

```
procedure TForm1.IdUDPServer1UDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread;
  AData: TArray<Byte>; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
```

For future reference, how do I fully qualify a type identifier in a generic method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fully qualified type identifiers are not (yet) supported. But you can circumvent this using a type alias:

```
type
  TMyByte = System.Byte;

procedure TForm1.IdUDPServer1UDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread;
  AData: TArray<TMyByte>; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have thought of this, I just expected there to be a direct method of qualifying the reference. I'll look at Quality Central to see if there is a bug report to vote for.

Comment: Using a manual typedef like this is needed only until Embarcadero gets around to finally stopping Delphi from resolving typedefs to their base types.  The OnUDPRead event technically tales a TIdBytes as a parameter, but every version of Delphi so far resolves it to either a DynamicArray<Byte> or TArray<Byte> directly, which is quite annoying and leads to these kinds of problems.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau - Ah, so the generated code is not specified in the IdUDPServer code, but is generated by the IDE? I never realized that.

Comment: @HMcG: whenever you double-click on an event in the Object Inspector, the IDE reads the component's RTTI, determines the signature of the event, resolves parameter and return value types, and generates the appropriate code for them. The component itself is not involved in that process at all, other than to declare the event type.